# cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<sales.ScanInfo> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I have the following code inside my c# console application, where i am calling a method called `getInfo` in parallel using `WhenAll()` method, as follow:-

```
class Program
    {
        static int concurrentrequests = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConcurrentRequests"]);
        static SemaphoreSlim throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: concurrentrequests);

        private static ScanInfo getInfo(string website)
        {
            throttler.Wait();
            ScanInfo si = new ScanInfo();
            int counter = 1;
            try
            {
              //code goes here..

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
              //code goes here
            }

            finally
            {

             throttler.Release();
            }

            }
            return si;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Marketing ipfd = new Marketing();
            try
            {
                using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) // call the PM API to get the account id 
                {
                   //code goes here
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {


            }
            var tasks = ipfd.companies.Select(c => getInfo(c.properties.website.value)).ToList();
            var results = Task.WhenAll(tasks);

           //code goes here..   
        }       
    }
```

but i am getting this exception:-

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from
System.Collections.Generic.List<Sales.ScanInfo> to
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>
```

so can anyone advice why i am getting this error?

Comment: you have no tasks or parallelism here. ipfd.companis has returned the actual data, not a list of tasks to wait on. Just use the data you got

Comment: Look at the `Select` statement code...what does `getInfo` return? Not a `Task`...

Comment: Lots of bad code here. It would be wiser if you studied: 1) what is `SemaphoreSlim` and when to use it? 2) study TPL. Don't use things unless you know what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var tasks = ipfd.companies.Select(c => getInfo(c.properties.website.value)).ToList();
  var results = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

tasks contains the results. YOu dont have to do any waiting at all. What make syou think you do. So just do

```
  var results  = ipfd.companies.Select(c => getInfo(c.properties.website.value)).ToList();
```

Comment: ok i gto your point, actually i use to do this when i use async methods + parallel inside my web application. but now i am writing a console app so no need for the async methods.. so if i use `var results  = ipfd.companies.Select(c => getInfo(c.properties.website.value)).ToList();` i will be calling the `getInfo` in parallel according to the `SemaphoreSlim throttler` i define?

Comment: can you please advice on my above comment?

Comment: you code will call getInfo in sequence one company at a time. SO there will only ever be one in progress. The throttler does nothing. You are running everything on one thread, serially

Comment: but inside my original code i used `Task.WhenAll(tasks);` to call the method in parallel...

Comment: Task.WhenAll does not run things in parallel. It waits for things you ran in parallel to finish. Why you changed the code from parallet to serial only you can answer

Comment: i use to have the `getinfo` method as async which return task, and with async + `whenall` i can get parallel .. but i were not able to define async methods inside console applications (unlike asp.net web applications)